# rmarkdown -rshiny- dynamic header option

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to have the header ouput based on the value user specifies in Rshiny.
Is there something equivalent to "\includegraphics" to paste user input via Rshiny?
Ref: \lhead{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{smikey.jpg}}

Comment: Can you please include a snippet of your code.